# Is there a way to scan a document and copy specific information into a word template?

Tags: python, java, printing, barcode-scanner

Essentially I need to be able to scan an invoice, pull only the names and then insert those names into a word template for printing. Preferably the solution will open multiple word documents at a time and the user will only have to hit print. The main issue is that there needs to be minimal interaction from a user perspective. I'm strong in python and weak in Java if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in Java using Tesseract OCR and Apache POI
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract 
https://poi.apache.org/